# What is the best way to initialise a javascript number?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to initialise a Javascript number, knowing the default value?

Should the number just be set, e.g.:

```
var anInteger = 0;
var aDecimal = 0.4;
```

or

```
var anInteger = new Number(0);
var aDecimal = new Number(0.4);
```

I have searched, but haven't found a definitive answer to this.

Comment: wow, 2 downvotes, why? maybe the use of the work "best" however I think this is a valid question.

Comment: I prefer `var anInteger = parseInt("0", 10);`. Seriously though, is there any reason why you'd _want_ to use your second option?

Comment: searched, but didn't see that question, thank  @Qantas 94 Heavy

Comment: @MarkRedman: yeah, sometimes SO's search is useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should almost always use the first solution. This makes a number **primitive** while using the `Number` constructor makes an **object**, an instance of `Number`, which is heavier.

And dealing with objects instead of primitive numbers is dangerous. For example :

```
new Number(4) === new Number(4)
```

is

```
false
```

The [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) class mainly exists so that you can call methods on numbers (for example `toFixed`) but you rarely need to call it explicitly as the promotion is automatic (for example `1..toFixed(0)` creates a temporary `Number` for that operation, object which is instantly dropped).

Comment: _"for example `1..toFixed(0)` creates a `Number`"_ - It creates a `Number` temporarily, but the whole expression returns a string. (That example is kind of confusing...)

Comment: @nnnnnn Commented to make it less confusing. I don't see any example which would better explain the automatic invisible promotion to Number.

Comment: Cool, the new wording addresses my concern. Thanks for the change.

Comment: Hey @dystroy, nice one.

Comment: One semi-related case: calling the `Number` constructor as a normal function produces a primitive number or a `NaN`. Similar to `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, but `parseInt("12junk")` is `12`, whereas `Number("12junk")` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally,you shouldn't worry about using Number objects because the browser automatically converts number literals to instances of the number class. I don't really know why someone would use them though.

It is suggested to use the first technique you mentioned i.e.

```
var num = 1;
```

To my understanding, adding `new` is just unnecessary for such a task.

```
new Number( x )
```

This creates a new wrapper object. I don't think there's a solid reason to use this.

Mozilla Documentations [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) the primary use for the `Number` object is:

a) If the argument can't be converted into a `Number`, like `NaN`.

Doing `var nice = new Number(1)` has no real advantage per say.